# Suppress StoreKit "Your purchase was successful" alert

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I have in-app purchases successfully implemented in my app but I would like to replace the "Your purchase was successful" alert (below) with my own, customised alert. The latter I can do but is there a way to suppress the generic system alerts for in-app purchases?

[image]

Comment: I think they are fully controlled by Apple and cannot be customised, i dont recall seeing any other apps with different text

Comment: Fair enough, thanks anyway!